# Pulumi python azure wrong resource name

Tags: pulumi, pulumi-azure, pulumi-python

I am trying to create a `sql.ServerVulnerabilityAssessment` resource in the following way:

```
server_vulnerability_assessment=sql.ServerVulnerabilityAssessment('sva',
    storage_container_path       = container_path,
    storage_account_access_key   = storage_account_primary_key,
    resource_group_name          = resource_group.name,
    server_name                  = sql_server.name,
    recurring_scans=sql.VulnerabilityAssessmentRecurringScansPropertiesArgs(
        is_enabled                  = True,
        email_subscription_admins   = False,
        emails                      = [
            "<emails>" # not showing obviously 
        ]
    )
)
```

where the

```
container_path = 'https://{}.blob.core.windows.net/{}'.format(storage_account.name,storage_container.name)
```

and i get the error:

```
  azure-native:sql:ServerVulnerabilityAssessment (sva):
    error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="DataSecurityInvalidUserSuppliedParameter" Message="\"Invalid parameter 'storageContainerPath'. Value should be a valid blob storage container endpoint (e.g. https://MyAccount.blob.core.windows.net/containername).\""
```

If I hardcode the values `storage_account.name` and `storage_container.name` it works without any error. Why cannot retrieve the values of these two properties there?

on running pulumi up if I choose to display the details i get the following for the storageContainerPath:

```
https://<pulumi.output.Output object at 0x7f1b0c8e9810>.blob.core.windows.net/<pulumi.output.Output object at 0x7f1b0c9236a0>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Obviously I can hardcode those values but why it does not work this way when for example the `sql_server.name` it gets correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage Account and Container names are Pulumi outputs, meaning they may not be known yet at the time when the program runs. You need to format the path using `Output.all`:

```
container_path = Output.all(storage_account.name, storage_container.name)
                       .apply(lambda l: f"https://{l[0]}.blob.core.windows.net/{l[1]}")
```

You can find more explanation and examples in [Inputs and Outputs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/).